# What are the classical compact connected lie groups?

Tags: general-topology, lie-groups

I think they are $SO(n),SU(n),Sp(n)$, and $Spin(n)$ but I'm not sure. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

They are groups $SO(n),Sp(n),SU(n),U(n)$. At least usually these are called "classical".
If you are interested in simple ones, you get $SO(n),Sp(n),SU(n)$.

Comment: Maybe if one adds the adjective "simple", otherwise, groups like U(n) would be also classical.

Comment: Oh, yes, you are right. Thank you! I corrected it.